# Copying one Google Sheet tab to another Google Sheet: renaming and formatting question

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a basic function that copies a sheet (tab) from one Google Sheet to another and renames it based on the contents of one specific cell.  However, the cell is formatted as a date in the source document, so while I was hoping for a new tab in the destination document named "7/4", I got "Sun Jul 04 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)".  Is there a way to just extract the cell value used for naming this tag as it appears on-screen? (ie, as M/DD format)?

```
function menuItem3() {
// copy data from Google Sheet A to Google Sheet B
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination_ID');  //sets specified spreadsheet as destination
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0]; 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A13");
  var value = cell.getValue();
sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(value);  //copies the sheet to destination and renames
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function menuItem3() {
// copy data from Google Sheet A to Google Sheet B
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination_ID');  //sets specified spreadsheet as destination
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0]; 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A13");
  var value = cell.getDisplayValue();//edit
sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(value);  //copies the sheet to destination and renames
}
```